# What's the correct way of adding static css/js on a VueJS app

Tags: css, vue.js

I have seen multiple questions related to this one, but I still couldn't understand what's the correct way of adding static CSS.
Adding the static CSS to the "static" folder the correct way?

Some of the suggestion I found on the internet were:

- Requiring the CSS on main.js
- Adding the CSS to the static folder and using a link tag pointing to the file on the static directory

I would like to know which one is the most correct.

Thank you.

Comment: You could have linked to the questions you mention, and written a list of the alternatives that were suggested there.

Comment: I have added the suggestions I found on the internet @RolandWeber.

Answer (score 1):

if you're using webpack you can just import your stylesheets in your main js config and all your components will get the css. like this :

```
require('./assets/css/main.css');
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, but I observed that it includes the stylesheet in a <style> tag. When requiring, for example Bootstrap or any other massive stylesheet, won't that be bad to have such a big style tag?

Answer (score 0):

Using sass, I import my app.scss file in the style tag of my main App.vue file

```
<style lang="scss">
  @import './styles/app.scss';
</style>
```

Then import any other sass files in my app.scss file.